# Let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×m}$ be a nonnegative matrix. Show that there exists an integral matrix that has the following properties:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×m}$ be a nonnegative matrix.

**Question:** Show that there exists an integral matrix $B ∈ \mathbb{Z}^{n×m}$ that has the following properties:

- Every entry of B is obtained by either rounding up or rounding down
  the corresponding entry of A.
- Every row-sum of B is obtained by either rounding up or rounding down
  the corresponding row-sum of A.
- Every column-sum of B is obtained by either rounding up or rounding
  down the corresponding column-sum of A.
- The sum of all entries of B is obtained by rounding up the sum of all
  entries of A.

It's not that hard to think of two matrices A and B where this would hold. Take for instance:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.7 & 0.7 \\
0.8 & 0.3 & 0.1
\end{bmatrix}$, B = 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

However, I do find it hard to formulate a method that finds a matrix B satisfying the properties for any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "nonnegative matrix", do you mean that all entries are non-negative?

Comment: @Arthur Yes that's what I mean!